# How does one prove the following statement about countability in set theory?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: \mathcal P ( \mathbb N ) \to \mathcal P ( \mathbb N )$ be any function. Then either the image of $f$ , $Im(f)$ , is uncountable or there exists an $A \in \mathcal P ( \mathbb N )$ such that $f^{−1} (\{A\})$ is uncountable (or both).

My idea would be to assume that the image is countable and then to prove that there exists an $A \in \mathcal P ( \mathbb N )$ such that $f^{−1} (\{A\})$ is uncountable. What I don't understand is that if $Im(f)$ is countable, then $Im(f) \neq \mathcal P ( \mathbb N )$, hence $f$ is not a bijection and the inverse should not exist. But to prove the above the inverse needs to exist. So where is the error in my reasoning? How can I prove it (the statement above, not the error in my reasoning)?

Comment: $f^{-1}(\{A\})$ is the set of all $B$ such that $f(B) = A$. The function need not have an actual function inverse for this to be defined.

Comment: @TokenToucan How do you prove that this set is uncountable?

Comment: now that the definition has been clarified, why don't you try yourself first.

Comment: @TokenToucan I did not know the fact that the countable union of countable sets is countable and this is where I got stuck. Next time I will share my attempt before asking away, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $Im(f)$ is countable. As

$$\mathcal P(\mathbb N ) = \bigcup_{A \in Im(f)} f^{-1}[\{A\}],$$

if all the $f^{-1}[\{A\}]$ were countable, so would be $\mathcal P(\mathbb N ) $ as a countable union of countable sets is countable. But that is contradicting the fact that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N ) $ is not countable (it has the power of the continuum).